# DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() returns empty ResultSet when use table name in lower case,but the right ResultSet in upper

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I use oracle 11g,and create a table like this:

```
create table test1(
id int,
name varchar(10),
inserttime date
)
```

Then I use the jdbc method

```
DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, "test1", null)
```

and get empty ResultSet.
but when I use

```
DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, "TEST1", null)
```

I can get the right ResultSet.

Why?

Comment: probably because Java is case sensitive and Oracle is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because internally, [`OracleDatabaseMetaData.getColumns()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns_java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String_) executes a query against the [`all_tab_columns`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm) data dictionary view, where it matches the table name pattern against `all_tab_columns.table_name`.

By convention, Oracle stores identifiers (such as the table name here) in data dictionaries in uppercase format. You can verify this by executing the following query in the db:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns t where t.table_name = 'TEST1';
```

The case-sensitivity of the table identifier here is indeed counter-intuitive, especially because table identifiers are case-insensitive in Oracle SQL.